# Redefine items in generated combinations from one list into terms of another list whose items are positionally linked

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

The list of values in the list `stuff` are the key or correspond to words in the list `words`.

```
stuff = [10170028,1,51,5,2,2,14,1,10,2,5,1,1]
words =['AGGGG','AUDIT + PARK','AUDIT + PENDING','AUDIT + QUOTE_CREATED'',AUDIT + QUOTE_DELETED',
         'AUDIT + QUOTE_REJECTED','AUDIT + QUOTE_UPDATED','AUDIT + RFQ_DELETED',
         'LIVE','PENDING','QUOTE_CREATED','REJECT','RFQ_DELETED']
```

All items in `stuff` are uniquely linked to an item in `words` by position, for instance `1` at `index 1` is linked to `AUDIT + PARK`, and `1` at `index 7` is linked to `LIVE`

I then use `itertools` to get each unique list that equals a specific sum:

```
new = []
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        if sum(subset) == 10170090:
            new.append(subset)
for x in new:
    print(x)
```

My `new` list consists of combinations

```
[(10170028, 1, 51, 10), (10170028, 51, 1, 10),...(10170028, 1, 51, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1), (10170028, 1, 51, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1)]
```

I need to convert each item in these sublists to the item they are linked to in `words`

Comment: I would suggest looking at dictionaries for your purpose.

Comment: How can `1` correspond to 4 different strings at the same time?

Comment: Please make the question clear. You need to explain properly how "values in `stuff` are keys or correspond to words in `words`". How can the value `1`,`2`,`5` each correspond to multiple different words? Is `value` just the sum of keys' values? Are some values zero or negative? It's important to clarify because many-to-one relationships restrict how dict can be used in solutions. Also, it helps to work out what the largest values are, so we can do an interval search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating your combinations, you can include the index of the number in the list so that you know which number (at a specific index) it was later on (since you can have duplicates):

```
for L in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
    # generate combinations of (index, number) tuples
    for subset in itertools.combinations(list(enumerate(stuff)), L): 
        if sum(x for i, x in subset) == 10170090:
            new.append(subset) # subset has index information
```

And now we can get the corresponding word for that number. So now this

```
for combo in new:
    print(combo)
    print([words[i] for i, x in combo]) # get word corresponding to index
```

prints:

```
((0, 10170028), (1, 1), (2, 51), (8, 10))                                                                                             
['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PARK', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'PENDING']                                                                               
((0, 10170028), (2, 51), (7, 1), (8, 10))                                                                                             
['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'LIVE', 'PENDING']                                                                                       
((0, 10170028), (2, 51), (8, 10), (11, 1))                                                                                            
['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'PENDING', 'RFQ_DELETED']                                                                                
...
```

Comment: Very nice I realized after I went through all that hassle that I should have went back to zip the indexes along when OP created the combinations and went this route but I had fun using iter along th way, good work!

Answer (score 2):

you could use the index

```
for id, val in enumerate(stuff):
    print(id, val, words[id])
```

or you could `zip()` it

```
print(list(zip(stuff, words)))
```

Comment: but your list do not match in length so you will have to account for that

Comment: @vash_the_stampede he cannot use a `list` in any case... so he has a way to build what ever data structure he wants. e.g. a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary, mapping elements from `stuff` to the corresponding word from `words`, then use a nested list comprehension to substitute the elements in `new`:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(stuff, words))
>>> [[d[x] for x in y] for y in new]
[['AGGGG', 'RFQ_DELETED', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'PENDING'],
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'RFQ_DELETED', 'PENDING'],
 ...
```

Comment: But `1` can reference a variety of items in `words

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple indexes that correspond to multiple keywords, and you are generating lists in `new` that are in sequence , for instance in the patter `[1, 51]` here `1` is equal to `AUDIT_PARK` but in a sequence like `[51, 10, 1]` , `1` now represents `RFQ_DELETED` .  You can use `iter` to go through as you match and move forward ot grab the proper `word` that correlates to that number in its position in `stuff`. I'm sure this could be cleaned up but this works correctly

```
new = []
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        if sum(subset) == 10170090:
            new.append(subset)

new = list(map(list, new))

for i in new:
    lst = iter(list(zip(stuff, words)))
    a = next(lst)
    for idx, item in enumerate(i):
        while True:
            if item == a[0] and a[1] == 'RFQ_DELETED':
                i[idx] = a[1]
                break
            elif item == a[0]:
                i[idx] = a[1]
                a = next(lst)
                break
            else:
                a = next(lst)

print(new)

[['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PARK', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'PENDING'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'LIVE', 'PENDING'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'PENDING', 'RFQ_DELETED'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PARK', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_CREATED,AUDIT + QUOTE_DELETED', 'REJECT'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_CREATED,AUDIT + QUOTE_DELETED', 'LIVE', 'REJECT'],  
 ... 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_CREATED,AUDIT + QUOTE_DELETED', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_REJECTED', 'LIVE', 'QUOTE_CREATED', 'RFQ_DELETED'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_REJECTED', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_UPDATED', 'LIVE', 'REJECT', 'RFQ_DELETED'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_REJECTED', 'LIVE', 'QUOTE_CREATED', 'REJECT', 'RFQ_DELETED'], 
 ['AGGGG', 'AUDIT + PENDING', 'AUDIT + QUOTE_REJECTED', 'LIVE', 'QUOTE_CREATED', 'REJECT', 'RFQ_DELETED']
]
```